# Highchart graph for continues status data in bar like timeserise

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I need support to create graph as in the image [image: Machine Status]

with the help of a timeline graph I have created this [created jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajitrishabh/ag1my8cb/8/)

I do not know how I can achieve my output. So that it matches with the image graph.
Like how I can create the **count** & **!** , **setting icon status** for the graph.

In the fiddle link you can see the gap between two data blocks it should be smooth bar line.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        type: 'timeline'
    },
    xAxis: {
       // type: 'datetime',
        visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 10,
        title: null,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Timeline of Space Exploration'
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled:false,
        style: {
            width: 20
        }
    },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: false,
            format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
                '{point.x:%d %b %Y}</span><br/>{point.label}'
        },
        marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
        },
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(1951, 5, 22),
            name: 'First dogs in space',
            label: 'First dogs in space',
            description: "Dezik and Tsygan were the first dogs to make a sub-orbital flight on 22 July 1951. Both dogs were recovered unharmed after travelling to a maximum altitude of 110 km."
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1957, 9, 4),
            name: 'First artificial satellite',
            label: 'First artificial satellite',
            description: "Sputnik 1 was the first artificial Earth satellite. The Soviet Union launched it into an elliptical low Earth orbit on 4 October 1957, orbiting for three weeks before its batteries died, then silently for two more months before falling back into the atmosphere."
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1959, 0, 4),
            name: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon'
        }]
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/timeline.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `timeline` series, you can use `x-range` one. It should be better for your needs.

To add custom elements such as icons or numbers `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` can be used. Check API links and demo with an example posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    height: 300,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          imgSize = 22,
          x = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + point.shapeArgs.width / 2 - imgSize / 2,
          y = point.plotY + chart.plotTop - point.shapeArgs.height - imgSize / 2,
          offsetTop = -5,
          svgElem;
        
        if (chart.customElemenst && chart.customElemenst.length) {
         chart.customElemenst.forEach(function(elem) {
           elem.destroy();
          });
        }
        
        chart.customElemenst = [];

        svgElem = chart.renderer.image(
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Info_icon-72a7cf.svg/256px-Info_icon-72a7cf.svg.png', 
          x,
          y + offsetTop,
          imgSize,
          imgSize
        ).add();
        
        chart.customElemenst.push(svgElem);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts X-range'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderRadius: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
      y: 0,
      partialFill: 0.25
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
      y: 1,
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
      y: 1,
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
      y: 1,
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
      y: 1,
      color: 'red'
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8f9o6dt0/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#image
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#add

Comment: Thanks but it is not same as what i want. i will having single values to the series data. i want to post this question on highchart support group but as i am new i could not add my question there.
as a customer of highchart is should be allowed to add my question.
please help me i need your support.

Comment: Highcharts have the same support here on StackOverflow as on highcharts support group. Your account has to be accepted first, then you can ask questions;) So, could you explain your issue more precisely? You can use timeline an add icons exactly the same way as in the example I posted above. What else do you need?

Comment: thanks again.
if you see my image the graph is showing machine status. machine will have 3 status red[not working],green[working],yellow[error] and it is continuous data like time Series data with every 1 minute or may be 30 second. so the graph should be smooth. if any red or yellow status is there i should be able to have the cumulative number count above the red/yellow bar.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, it was the description of the project and not the precise issue you have. Check this example with timeline series, custom icon and number above a point: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1y7mzLca/1/. To make live data you can use `addPoint()` or `update()` - API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update. If you have trouble to build the whole project you can contact with a Black Label company, they are experts in Highcharts and custom projects: https://www.blacklabel.pl/.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. But the situation is such that we have to complete project POC asap.
We are new to highcharts and I do not know BlackLabel is registered company in siemens(my company) or not. If we can get the poc done we can discuss on the project with blacklable. How i can remove the space between two time blocks so that it look smooth.
The image which I have provided are also done in Highcharts but do not know how?

Comment: Ok, I understand. So, you can remove the space between blocks just by setting points in equal periods of time. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/scnzye9u/

Comment: i am talking about space between two data point. the white space

Comment: You can remove it by setting `series.timeline.marker.lineWidth = 0`. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4rf1zx0h/. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.marker.lineWidth